# Prevent svg <use> elements being re-rendered when properties of other elements change in IE/Edge

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to use svg 'use' elements as icons in a div that is a part of a div displayed as table. It will be much faster when those 'use' elements are loaded for the first time than creating an 'svg' element for each icon.

However, when the properties of elements in other divs within the same table div, all the 'use' elements get re-rendered (see the below screenshot of IE profiler of a hover effect). So this makes interaction with other elements slower. And the re-render only happens in IE/Edge not in Chrome.
[IE profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkdBQ.png)

Anyone happens to know how to prevent the 'use' elements being re-rendered?

Comment: Share a small sample of you code to show the re-rendering problem.

Comment: Sorry for late update. I've created a sample of the similar case: https://jsfiddle.net/y99cLng3/2/   The two divs are two table-cells. The black arrows are 'use' elements, and the white overlay is hoverable. If you open the code in IE and use the profiler to record the hover effect of the overlay, you'll see in profiler -> Timeline -> Layout that the use elements are re-rendered again. However, if you comment out row.style.fill in mouseOver and mouseOut and try the hover again, the use elements won't be re-rendered. Thanks!!